# Why do I get "'UIView' does not have a member named 'image'" and how can I fix it?

Tags: swift, error-handling

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

    myCell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderimage.png")

    myCell.username.text = "User 123"

    myCell.message.text = "Message"

    return myCell
  }
```

On the line which says:

`myCell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderimage.png")`,

> I get the error: "'UIView' does not have a member called 'image'".

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I do not use UITableView, but my guess may be is postedImage optional?  so you need to add the ! to get it to work myCell.postedImage!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderimage.png")

Comment: how is `postedImage` declared?

Comment: Make sure you declare the postedImage variable in the custom class 'cell'.

Comment: postedImage is declared in the cell class like this: class cell: UITableViewCell {

    IBOutlet weak var postedImage: UIView!
    
    IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
    
    IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
    
}

Comment: Have I declared it properly, and if so, why do I then get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your outlet is declared as type

`IBOutlet weak var postedImage: UIView!`

You are trying to access a property `image` on `UIView` which doesn't exist hence the compiler warning.

as a rough guess you need define what `postedImage` is correctly

`IBOutlet weak var postedImage: UIImageView!`

but you may also have dropped the wrong kind of object `UIView` into your `XIB` in which case you'll need to fix that first.

Comment: Why would I go about defining what postedImage is correctly?